# Expresion regular que valide cedula PHP

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo una expresion regular que valide la cedula de identidad venezolana y lo logre

```
if(preg_match_all("/(\d*[0-9]{2})/", $cedula, $resultado)){

    print_r($resultado);
} else {

    echo "No hubo resultado";
}
```

el problema es que yo quiero que el usuario ingrese los valores de esta manera:

```
$cedula = 18.842.389;
```

es decir, quiero que mi expresion regular tenga en cuenta los . que el usuario ingrese

Comment: edita tu pregunta y señala en específico que quieres lograr o sobre que trabajas, ya que de lo contrario queda muy amplia y se escapa de las reglas de foro; todo esto para que no reciba votos negativos y sea cerrada

Comment: https://regexr.com/

Comment: Hola bueno necesito saber con que expresion regular le indico que quiero recibir caracteres especiales (como un . & () @, etcc...)

Comment: ok pero entonces modifica tu pregunta y coloca el texto de ejemplo que vas a ingresar y la salida que esperas recibir una vez que se procese la regex

Comment: Para aquellos que no somos de venezuela ¿con qué formato se rigen las cedulas allí? en cada país esto tiene unas normas diferentes, sería bueno que indiques que premisas se deben cumplir.

Comment: $cedula = 18.842.389 ese es el formato

Comment: El resultado del print_r me dan bien, los dos primeros digitos al principio y despues los tres y tres, pero no me esta validando los puntos (.) quiero saber como le indico a la regexp que me tenga en cuenta caracteres especiales (. & % $ #), etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu expresión regular debería quedar del modo siguiente

```
<?php
$cedula = "18.842.389";

if(preg_match_all("/(\.d*[0-9]{2})/", $cedula, $resultado)){

    print_r($resultado);
} else {

    echo "No hubo resultado";
}
```

> Como notas, antes de la letra d y luego del 0 al 9 que verificará que
>   solo sean números le agregamos el punto; haces la prueba y con punto
>   muestra el array con las posiciones y si los quitas o le pones otra
>   cosa como guíon medio te muestra **No hubo resultado**

### Pero yo necesito que sean con cualquier caracter especial

Entonces en lugar del símbolo de punto colocas **\W** pero en mayúscula y ya con eso te valida que metas entre las cifras caracteres especiales mira

```
<?php


$cedula = "18.842.389";

if(preg_match_all("/(\W\d*[0-9]{2})/", $cedula, $resultado)){

   print_r($resultado);
} else {

    echo "No hubo resultado";
}
```

Te dejo un listado para caracteres especiales:

> $  Match al final del string 
>  \s Match con cualquier
>   espacio en blanco 
>  \d   Match con cualquier dígito 
>  \D    Match
>   con cualquier caracter que no sea un dígito 
>  \w Match con
>   cualquier caracter que pueda ser parte de una palabra (letra, número,
>   guión bajo)
>  \W  Match con cualquier caracter que NO pueda ser
>   parte de una palabra (letra, número, guión bajo)
>  \A Inicio de un
>   string.
>  \z  Final de un string.

Comment: Gracias. Me guie con lo que comentaste e incluso mejore la expresion regular, dejaré el resultado aqui;  /^[0-9]{2}+\.d*[0-9]{3}+\.d*[0-9]{3}/

Comment: que bueno te quedó de hecho agregue mas contenido a mi respuesta por si gustas revisar @JOSEHERRADA

Comment: perfecto validaste incluso la cantidad de caracteres que debe haber entre cada caracter especial